# Gmail on Firefox - slow?

Tags: firefox, gmail

Is it just me or has anyone else found Gmail getting really slow on Firefox? I've used Gmail for years and it's always been fast and responsive. I can now wait several seconds, hovering over an email, for the delete etc buttons to appear. I've noticed this more and more over the last 2-3 weeks. Other pages are fine so it's not the browser or my connection.

Using Chrome it seems fine - but I don't want to use Chrome.

I'm using FireFox 82 on 18.04.

Thanks

Comment: No issues here with Gmail on FF82.0 with 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Try using gmail in Firefox's private mode. The slowness could be attributed to the fact that your main browser is Firefox. So things like cookies, cache, etc can accumulate over time and make a website slower. If it's not slow, just clear cookies and cache in normal mode and try again. Other than that, it's hard to give a proper answer to your question.

Comment: From the hamburger menu, open Web Developer --> Network and open or reload the page.If something is loading slowly outside of Firefox, you should see it. If it seems to be Firefox, you could log out and clear the google cookies and site data, then log back in. That data gets to be a lot after awhile.

Comment: Thanks all. The activity in the network tab was immense, so very hard to see if something was sluggish. I've turned off Google Meet and that seems to have improved things.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that Google apps like gmail and calendar get slower over time, until they take minutes to fully load in Firefox for Linux (88.01, no extensions enabled). If I do a browser reset, they get fast again at first, then gradually slow, week after week, until I have to go and do something else while they're loading. I've been having this problem consistently for at least a year.

The problem occurs just at browser startup. If I close and reopen those apps later in a browser session, there's no issue.

Answer (score -1):

Same case here I am using firefox 89 in kubutu 21.04 but the problem sees to be form 86 or 87, not only gmail few more pages also load very slowly or lag very much. Specifically saying when ever I open apple page the whole browser crashes along with a lag in my system. Also the CPU usage during using firefox is very high around 75-85% which is a main reason for the system lag. I don't know why firefox team scrued up with their updates. Fortunately I got a sollutin for this if you are using Ubuntu or its derivatives then don't use the default firefox instead of this use the flatfak version, it seemed that flatpak version don't have those bugs, may be your theme mismatch with system but it's very usable.